# $f_n$ sequence of functions that converge uniformly but not in $C^1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for a sequence of $C^{1}$ functions $(f_n)$ on a compact set such that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty}$ uniformly, but $f \notin C^1$?

Does anybody know such a sequence (preferably simple and straightforward)?

Comment: @DavidMitra $x^n$ doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,1].$

Comment: @zhw. I completely misread the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Weierstrass function (or some variant of it) would work, if you take $f_n$ to be the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series.  More information can be found here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

In fact, the Weierstrass function, being a uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions (in fact, $C^1$ functions), is continuous on any compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$.  But the Weierstrass function is not differentiable at any point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: If you only want non-differentiability at a point (say $x=0$) you can also use $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$, as these converge uniformly on $[-M,M]$ (for $M>0$) to $f(x)=|x|$.  All the $f_n$'s are $C^1$ while $f(x)$ is not $C^1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I would rather prefer a simpler example and in exchange I'd be fine with having the non-differentiability at a single point.

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example: Let $f_n(x) = x^{2+1/n}\sin (1/x), x\in(0,1], f_n(0) = 0.$ Then each $f_n\in C^1[0,1],$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x) = x^2\sin (1/x)$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ This infamous $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere but its derivative is discontinuous at $0.$

Additionally the Weierstrass approximation theorem says any continuous function on $[a,b]$ is the uniform limit of polynomials, so you can have a field day with that once you know it.